# javax.json - Build JsonObject with arraylist and one separated attribute

Tags: java, json, arraylist, response, jsonobjectrequest

I have a method that should return a `Response` with a `JsonObject` (with arraylist) exactly like the code at the bottem of this article. This is a java `@GET` method. I know how to build a `jsonobject` with `json.createObjectBuilder` like:

```
 JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("name", "item").add("user", user.getUser()).build();
```

But I dont how to build like the code below.
So I have to do an add with the name "items", this is an arraylist. Every item has four attributes: id, name, bool and another arraylist reserveItems (reserveItems can be null). After this I have to do an add with name length and value 687.

```
{
              "items" :[
                           {
                              "id"         : 1,
                              "name"       : "Item1",
                              "bool"       : true,
                              "reserveItems": []
                           },
                           {
                              "id"         : 2,
                              "name"       : "Item2",
                              "bool"       : false,
                              "reserveItem": []
                           }
              ],
              "length"  :687
    }
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand what is your issue, please, consider reviewing and correcting your post text, and, probably, add more code of your _"method that should return a Response with a JsonObject_. From what I understood, you, probably, want to crate model class for your json with, jackson, for exapmple, and then return it in your REST Endpoint, I assume, something like this `Response.status(Status.OK).entity(yourJsonRepresntObject).build()`. Let us know if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JsonObjectBuilder interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html), you can obtain your JsonObject in this way:

```
                JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("items", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                        .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("id", 1)
                                .add("name", "Item1")
                                .add("bool", true)
                                .add("reserveItems", Json.createArrayBuilder())
                        )
                        .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("id", 2)
                                .add("name", "Item2")
                                .add("bool", false)
                                .add("reserveItems", Json.createArrayBuilder())
                        )
                )
               .add("length", 687)
               .build();

               System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try your solution. I will let u know if it worked out.